# Getting variable from pretty url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've done things very similar before but for some reason I'm having a little difficulty with the specific scenario.  I want to pass a folder path as a variable and make it look pretty.

I have a working url like:

```
http://mysite.com/albums/index.php?p=folder/subfolder/
```

I can view it without the 'index.php' like:

```
http://mysite.com/albums/?p=folder/subfolder/
```

What I want is a pretty url that looks like this:

```
http://mysite.com/albums/folder/subfolder/
```

Basically, anything after /albums/ should be a single variable.  I've played with my .htaccess RewriteRule a bunch and can't seem to get it working. (get 404 errors)  This is what I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^albums/(.*)$ albums/?p=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is what i use though every call is directed to my index.php file and from there i do anything with it

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It doesn't seem to be passing the variable to my page. I use this to check "if (!isset($_GET['p']))".  I might be able to tweak this to meet my needs though, I'll keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: no it doesn't what it does is that all url request are sent to your root index file and you can now do sumtin like this $url  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which can now be split like this $params  = explode("/", $url);

Comment: Thanks omoabobade, I was able to figure out what I was trying to do by using the suggestions you made.

Answer (score 0):

Change `(.*)` into `(.+)` to ensure there is at least one character after `/` , otherwise your rule loops...

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I'm getting a 500 error.  I'll investigate (.+) more and maybe with some tweaks I'll get it figured out.  Thanks.